# redirect to state and show success message

Tags: angularjs

In a simple CRUD app I would expect after a successful update, it would redirect back to the list of items with an "update successful" message. How would you accomplish this is angular 1.3.x? My initial thoughts were to do something like this, but having to have a success variable in the URL is silly.

```
$state.go('app.list', {
  success: {
    show: true,
    msg: name + ' has been updated successfully.'
  }
});
```

Anyone have a decent solution for this?

Comment: Can you create a plunker or jsfiddle, this code doesn't really address the structure of your app. why not just use location service with passed parameter? $location.path('/mypath/?message='+msg);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is creating a service for handling my alerts. Here is the service code:

```
app.factory('AlertService', function () {
  var success = {},
      error = {},
      alert = false;
  return {
    getSuccess: function () {
      return success;
    },
    setSuccess: function (value) {
      success = value;
      alert = true;
    },
    getError: function () {
      return error;
    },
    setError: function (value) {
      error = value;
      alert = true;
    },
    reset: function () {
      success = {};
      error = {};
      alert = false;
    },
    hasAlert: function () {
      return alert;
    }
  }
});
```

And I simply set it when I need to like so:

```
AlertService.setSuccess({ show: true, msg: name + ' has been updated successfully.' });
```

And check for it on the page that would display it like this:

```
if (AlertService.hasAlert()) {
  $scope.success = AlertService.getSuccess();
  AlertService.reset();
}
```