# How to show a message when navigating from one page to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

On success message I want to navigate from uploaded page to customer page and highlight my alert as success , but my alert is not getting open. Need solution

**Upload.js**

```
if (status == 200){
    $state.go('customer', {"id": $scope.customer});    
    $rootScope.$emit('custSucess');
}
```

**customer.js**

```
$rootScope.$on('custSucess',function(event){
         $scope.message = {
                content: [{
                   title: '',
                   msg:'hi'
                }],
                   type: 'success'
                };
});
```

Comment: instead of $rootScope.$emit('custSucess'); try $rootScope.$emit('dealerSuccess');

Comment: sorry its a typo, I given custsuccess only , still it not highlighted.

Comment: My angular is a bit rusty but 1. are you sure your code is reaching the body of that if condition? and 2. What happens if you switch the two lines, have the rootscope.emit first then state.go second

Answer (score 1):

So what I ended up doing is creating a service for handling my alerts. Here is the service code:

```
app.factory('AlertService', function () {
  var success = {},
      error = {},
      alert = false;
  return {
    getSuccess: function () {
      return success;
    },
    setSuccess: function (value) {
      success = value;
      alert = true;
    },
    getError: function () {
      return error;
    },
    setError: function (value) {
      error = value;
      alert = true;
    },
    reset: function () {
      success = {};
      error = {};
      alert = false;
    },
    hasAlert: function () {
      return alert;
    }
  }
});
```

//And I simply set it when I need to like so:

```
AlertService.setSuccess({ show: true, msg: name + ' has been updated successfully.' });
```

//And check for it on the page that would display it like this:

```
if (AlertService.hasAlert()) {
  $scope.success = AlertService.getSuccess();
  AlertService.reset();
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: #Mohsin try to post your own answer.Never post anyone others answer as your own.You just copied this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792360/9675804